# Emacs and gdb - Show code for function in backtrace

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, emacs, gdb

I am debugging a C++ program. Suppose I am sitting at a breakpoint in gdb and I do `bt 50`. This will generate the backtrace and show me the call stack with 50 functions that were run in the process of execution reaching where it is now.

Sometimes, I want to quickly examine the code for one of the functions in the backtrace call stack. I know how to do this on Visual Studio. Visual Studio maintains `call stack` similar to gdb `backtrace`. On Visual Studio, I can simply double-click a function in the call stack and Visual Studio takes me to the code for that function, even opening the file for me if not opened. Very convenient.

I was wondering if there was a gdb command to show code around a symbol name in backtrace. Currently, the only way I know is to manually find the file and open it in emacs, and then do a search in emacs to take me to the function. Please tell me if there is a better way so it becomes convenient like in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several choices, depending on how you are running gdb.

One simple way is to run gdb inside emacs.  You can use `M-x gdb` (or `M-x gud-gdb`, which is a bit more old-school) to do this.  When running gdb in emacs, simply selecting a frame will cause the source to be visited in emacs, and point will move to the line in question.  "Selecting a frame" can be done via the `up`, `down`, and `frame` commands.

If you're running gdb outside of emacs, and want to continue doing this, then there are still options.

One approach is the `edit` command.  Make sure to set your `EDITOR` environment variable to use `emacsclient` and set up emacs to respond to this (like `M-x server-start`).

Then in gdb, select some frame and you can see that frame's source with `edit *$pc`.

Another approach that some people like is to use the gdb "tui".  This is a curses-based interface that shows the source in the terminal.

Yet another approach is to use one of the many gdb GUIs.